# set dynamic equal height of two uiview depends on their subview using autolayout?

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have one superview in that view there are two subview.
I have set equal height of that two view. Those subview height changing respect to label height in it.

This is first screen that i have implemented. It works when label 2 height is greater then label 1 height changes with respect to label 2 height.

[image]

This is first screen. It work properly but another situation it is not working when label 1 height is greater than label 2 height then it's not working expected.
output like following screen
[image]
As expected label 2 need to adjust with respect label 1 but then also label 1 is adjusted with respect to label 2.

so how to apply constraint for set equal height for two view depends on their subview height.

Comment: In your console do you see any constraints breaking ?

Comment: Have you set label1 and Label2 heights Equal constraint?

Comment: Would you like to achieve that programmatically or using interface builder?

Comment: @ArturOlszak I want using Interface builder

Answer (score 1):

You can make your label heigh dynamically

Call a method for `UILabel` height

```
-(CGSize) getContentSize_Label:(UILabel*) myLabelView{
    return [myLabelView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(myLabelView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
}
```

and set label heigh like

```
   myLabelView.frame = CGRectMake(myLabelView.frame.origin.x, myLabelView.frame.origin.y, myLabelView.frame.size.width, [self getContentSize_Label:myLabelView].height);
```

and set

```
  myLabelView.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is most probably equal height constraint.

Select two container views of the labels and then go to Xcode/Editor/Pin/ and select Height equally.

I've just checked it and its working for me.